# Time Difference In Hour Minutes Seconds Php

Tags: php, datetime, time

Am using formula like this

```
<?php
//Coming From Mobile Phone
$Currenttime   = 12:40:00;
//Server time Is Current Time of various timezone like(America/Chicago,America/Denver..)
$ServerTime   = 12:55:00;
//Scheduletime is coming from database
$ScheduleTime = 14:45:00;

$ExactTime    = ($Currenttime - $ServerTime) + $ScheduleTime

?>
```

I need Exact Time is like this 15:00:00

Answer (score 2):

You should use the DateTime class for this:

```
$Currenttime  = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', "12:40:00");
$ServerTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', "12:55:00");
$ScheduleTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', "14:45:00");

$ExactTime    = $ScheduleTime->add($Currenttime->diff($ServerTime));
```

Comment: Being correct, you would need to clone like `$Exact = clone ($Currenttime->sub($ServerTime)->add($ScheduleTime));` But however, good solution!

Comment: Sorry for the operator - normally I am a .net Developer :)

Comment: No worries, the basic statement of the answer is what counts.

Comment: `Warning: DateTime::sub() expects parameter 1 to be DateInterval, object given`

Comment: How Can I use in PHP?

Comment: The problem is fixed now

Comment: Thank You no result for me Empty!                         current_time:13:14:00
ServerTime:13:43:09
start_time:14:45:00                                       ExactTime:'';

Comment: Thanks Its working but how I get date alone form this object DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-08-19 15:41:52
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
)